# php include_once path

Tags: php, file, path, include

I am trying to find a way to make the `include_once();` path start from the beginning directory and then find the path e.g. instead of `../../../path/to/file` I would have `/path/to/file`. If I do do that `/path/to/file` it says no such file or directory, here is my direct code

```
<?php
include_once("/assets/page_assets.php");
?>
```

Comment: `path start from the beginning directory` from the root of the webserver? `/path/to/file` is the path from the root of the file system!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have an Apache server

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/assets/page_assets.php");
?>
```

`"/assets/page_assets.php"` means `from the root of the disk`, not from the root folder of the server. If you are talking about some other `beginning directory` then define physical path (path in the file system of the server, not the web path) to it as a separate constant/variable and prepend it to the included path as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify include path explicitly:

```
<?php ini_set('include_path',ini_get('include_path').':../../../:');  ?>
```

But as Cheery mentioned in comment, you must include your file without leading slash:

```
<?php
include_once("assets/page_assets.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this you must use the path from the root.  In some cases this might look like `/var/www/mysite.com/assets/page_assets.php`.  One way to find that path is to use `__FILE__` (That's 2 underscores both in front and behind).  If you echo that from a file, it will show you the complete path.  You should be able to use that to set the correct full path.

Answer (score 0):

Start your script with `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

Now you can call `include("path/to/file.php");` and it will start looking from the webroot.